# Cómo obtener todos los elementos <li> utilizando Selenium si no tiene clase o id

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy automatizando una página web, pero tengo un problema, porque el elemento `<li>` no tiene un identificador para obtener lo que necesito.
Entonces lo intenté con el texto pero tampoco funciona porque no es un select, estoy intentando con className o cssSelector.

Hacerlo con XPATH es una mala practica.

```
IWebElement processes = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='formCreateProject']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/ul");
IList<IWebElement> process = processes.FindElements(By.CssSelector("li"));
IWebElement selectProcess = process[34];
```

No quiero hacerlo con Xpath, porque el cliente necesita que se elija la opción por nombre, como por ejemplo "Administración".
Esto no funcionó: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268264/how-to-get-a-html-list-without-class-selenium-c-sharp

El código Html de la página es el siguiente:

```
<div class="selectricWrapper selectric-form-control  selectric-required selectricOpen selectricAbove">
<div class="selectricHideSelect">
    <select
        id="process"
        title="Proceso"
        class="form-controlrequired"
        data-bind="options: $root.projectData.Processes",
        optionsValue: "Id",
        optionsText: 'Name',
        value: projectData.ProcessId,
        optionsCaption: selectCaption,
        uniqueName: true,
        name="ko_unique_1"
        tabindex="0"
    >
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        <option value="1">Actualización</option>
        <option value="2">Adecuación</option>
        <option value="3">Administración</option>
        <option value="4">Adquisición</option>
        <option value="5">Alfabetización</option>
        <option value="6">Ampliación</option>
        <option value="7">Análisis</option>
        <option value="8">Aplicación</option>
        <option value="9">Aportes</option>
        <option value="10">Apoyo</option>
        <option value="11">Aprovechamiento</option>
        <option value="12">Asesoria</option>
        <option value="13">Asistencia</option>
        <option value="14">Capacitación</option>
        <option value="15">Capitalización</option>
        <option value="82">Caracterización</option>
        <option value="16">Compromiso</option>
        <option value="76">Conformación</option>
        <option value="17">Conservación</option>
        <option value="77">Consolidación</option>
        <option value="18">Construcción</option>
        <option value="94">Contribución</option>
        <option value="19">Control</option>
        <option value="20">Demarcación</option>
        <option value="21">Desarrollo</option>
        <option value="22">Descontaminación</option>
        <option value="23">Diagnostico</option>
        <option value="24">Difusión</option>
        <option value="25">Diseño</option>
        <option value="26">Distribución</option>
        <option value="27">Divulgación</option>
        <option value="28">Dotación</option>
        <option value="29">Edición</option>
        <option value="81">Elaboración</option>
        <option value="30">Erradicación</option>
        <option value="31">Estudio</option>
        <option value="32">Estudios</option>
        <option value="85">Experimentación</option>
        <option value="33">Exploración</option>
        <option value="34">Explotación</option>
        <option value="78">Extensión</option>
        <option value="35">Forestación</option>
        <option value="75">Formación</option>
        <option value="36">Formulación</option>
        <option value="37">Fortalecimiento</option>
        <option value="96">Generación</option>
        <option value="38">Habilitación</option>
        <option value="39">Identificación</option>
        <option value="40">Implantación</option>
        <option value="41">Implementación</option>
        <option value="42">Incremento</option>
        <option value="95">Indemnización</option>
        <option value="74">Innovación</option>
        <option value="43">Instalación</option>
        <option value="44">Inventario</option>
        <option value="45">Inversiones</option>
        <option value="46">Investigación</option>
        <option value="47">Levantamiento</option>
        <option value="48">Mantenimiento</option>
        <option value="49">Mejoramiento</option>
        <option value="101">Modernización</option>
        <option value="50">Nacionalización</option>
        <option value="51">Normalización</option>
        <option value="80">Optimización</option>
        <option value="83">Pavimentación</option>
        <option value="100">Prestación</option>
        <option value="52">Prevención</option>
        <option value="53">Privatización</option>
        <option value="102">Producción</option>
        <option value="86">Programación</option>
        <option value="54">Protección</option>
        <option value="92">Reconciliación</option>
        <option value="84">Reconstrucción</option>
        <option value="55">Recopilación</option>
        <option value="56">Recreación</option>
        <option value="57">Recuperación</option>
        <option value="58">Reforestación</option>
        <option value="59">Rehabilitación</option>
        <option value="93">Reintegración</option>
        <option value="60">Remodelación</option>
        <option value="61">Renovación</option>
        <option value="62">Reparación</option>
        <option value="88">Reparación</option>
        <option value="63">Reposición</option>
        <option value="64">Restauración</option>
        <option value="89">Restitución</option>
        <option value="65">Restructuración</option>
        <option value="87">Revisión</option>
        <option value="66">Saneamiento</option>
        <option value="91">Satisfacción</option>
        <option value="67">Servicio</option>
        <option value="68">Sistematización</option>
        <option value="69">Subsidio</option>
        <option value="70">Suministro</option>
        <option value="71">Sustitución</option>
        <option value="72">Titulación</option>
        <option value="73">Traslado</option>
    </select></div>
<div class="selectric">
    <p class="label">Seleccione</p><b class="button">▾</b>
</div>
<div class="selectricItems" tabindex="-1" style="width: 918px; height: 162px;">
    <div class="selectricScroll">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">Seleccione</li>
            <li class="">Actualización</li>
            <li class="">Adecuación</li>
            <li class="">Administración</li>
            <li class="">Adquisición</li>
            <li class="">Alfabetización</li>
            <li class="">Ampliación</li>
            <li class="">Análisis</li>
            <li class="">Aplicación</li>
            <li class="">Aportes</li>
            <li class="">Apoyo</li>
            <li class="">Aprovechamiento</li>
            <li class="">Asesoria</li>
            <li class="">Asistencia</li>
            <li class="">Capacitación</li>
            <li class="">Capitalización</li>
            <li class="">Caracterización</li>
            <li class="">Compromiso</li>
            <li class="">Conformación</li>
            <li class="">Conservación</li>
            <li class="">Consolidación</li>
            <li class="">Construcción</li>
            <li class="">Contribución</li>
            <li class="">Control</li>
            <li class="">Demarcación</li>
            <li class="">Desarrollo</li>
            <li class="">Descontaminación</li>
            <li class="">Diagnostico</li>
            <li class="">Difusión</li>
            <li class="">Diseño</li>
            <li class="">Distribución</li>
            <li class="">Divulgación</li>
            <li class="">Dotación</li>
            <li class="">Edición</li>
            <li class="">Elaboración</li>
            <li class="">Erradicación</li>
            <li class="">Estudio</li>
            <li class="">Estudios</li>
            <li class="">Experimentación</li>
            <li class="">Exploración</li>
            <li class="">Explotación</li>
            <li class="">Extensión</li>
            <li class="">Forestación</li>
            <li class="">Formación</li>
            <li class="">Formulación</li>
            <li class="">Fortalecimiento</li>
            <li class="">Generación</li>
            <li class="">Habilitación</li>
            <li class="">Identificación</li>
            <li class="">Implantación</li>
            <li class="">Implementación</li>
            <li class="">Incremento</li>
            <li class="">Indemnización</li>
            <li class="">Innovación</li>
            <li class="">Instalación</li>
            <li class="">Inventario</li>
            <li class="">Inversiones</li>
            <li class="">Investigación</li>
            <li class="">Levantamiento</li>
            <li class="">Mantenimiento</li>
            <li class="">Mejoramiento</li>
            <li class="">Modernización</li>
            <li class="">Nacionalización</li>
            <li class="">Normalización</li>
            <li class="">Optimización</li>
            <li class="">Pavimentación</li>
            <li class="">Prestación</li>
            <li class="">Prevención</li>
            <li class="">Privatización</li>
            <li class="">Producción</li>
            <li class="">Programación</li>
            <li class="">Protección</li>
            <li class="">Reconciliación</li>
            <li class="">Reconstrucción</li>
            <li class="">Recopilación</li>
            <li class="">Recreación</li>
            <li class="">Recuperación</li>
            <li class="">Reforestación</li>
            <li class="">Rehabilitación</li>
            <li class="">Reintegración</li>
            <li class="">Remodelación</li>
            <li class="">Renovación</li>
            <li class="">Reparación</li>
            <li class="">Reparación</li>
            <li class="">Reposición</li>
            <li class="">Restauración</li>
            <li class="">Restitución</li>
            <li class="">Restructuración</li>
            <li class="">Revisión</li>
            <li class="">Saneamiento</li>
            <li class="">Satisfacción</li>
            <li class="">Servicio</li>
            <li class="">Sistematización</li>
            <li class="">Subsidio</li>
            <li class="">Suministro</li>
            <li class="">Sustitución</li>
            <li class="">Titulación</li>
            <li class="last">Traslado</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><input class="selectricInput" tabindex="0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que se puede hacer en estos casos es localizar algun ancestro que contenga todos los li como descendientes. Por ejemplo, el `<div class="selectricScroll">`

```
IList<IWebElement> process = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath(".//div[@class='selectricScroll']//li"));
```

Por otro lado si vas a interactuar con uno en concreto, te recomiendo localizar ese li directamente:

```
IWebElement selectProcess = driver.FindElementByXPath(".//li[text()='Recuperación']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo obtendría el `Select` directamente, desde ahí utilizaría `value` o el texto para obtenerlo directamente:

```
Select DrpdwnEjemplo = new Select (Navegador.findElement(By.id("selectProductoMassive")));
DrpdwnEjemplo.selectByVisibleText("VALE DESPENSA CHIP");
```